# Why Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects is violated in hazelcast Map

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

This is more of a design question. I would like to know why hazelcast uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` of binary (serialized) forms of the objects instead of the ones provided by the composite key objects.

I faced a problem in which I had to associate some metadata (`lastModifiedTimeStamp`, `lastModifiedNode` etc.) with the key object, which is not possible because of this violation.

While I do understand that there are other ways to tackle my problem, making these attributes a part of the key (followed by overriding `hashCode()` / `equals()` method to exclude the metadata) would've been a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. There are multiple reasons for this, but one of them might be this:

We keep keys in a serialized (=binary) form. In other to use regular hashCode() and equals() from your domain objects we would need to have them in de-serialized (object) format.

Just this fact alone means:
- You would always need .class file of your domain objects on all cluster members. When members are dealing with serialized blobs only then you don't need that.

- You could either keep keys in de-serialized format only, but then you would have to serialize them for each remote request -> performance penalty. Hazelcast is build on an assumption most your operations are remote.
- Or you could maintain keys on both serialized & deserialized form -> space penalty.

I'm sure there are other reasons; These are just a few I can think of from top of my head.

Credits - Jaromir Hamala - Hazelcast mailing list.

Comment: @pveentjer, anything else that you could think of ?